# ¿Como abrir un archivo pdf con Django?

Tags: django, windows, pdf, archivo

Soy nuevo en Django, estoy usando Windows 7, Django 1.11 y Python 2.5.2, requiero abrir un archivo PDF del disco local, cuando se hace click a un botón ¿Cómo puedo lograr esa acción?

Gracias

Comment: Para mostrar un archivo de pdf te debes de ayudar con tecnologias de front como javascript, lo que podrias y debes hacer con django es buscar el archivo pdf en el disco local del servidor y enviarlo tal cual.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ¿tienes algún código de ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Aquí ya hay una pregunta similar de como descargar un PDF en django.

[Descargar un PDF en Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/29091/descargar-un-pdf-en-django/29115)